# Duplicate "values" for some key in map-reduce java program

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new in mapreduce and hadoop (hadoop 3.2.3 and java 8).
I am trying to separate some lines based on a symbol in a line.
Example: "q1,a,q0," should be return ('a',"q1,a,q0,") as (key, value).
My dataset contains ten(10) lines , five(5) for key 'a' and five for key 'b'.

I expect to get 5 line for each key but i always get five for 'a' and 10 for 'b'

Data

```
A,q0,a,q1;A,q0,b,q0;A,q1,a,q1;A,q1,b,q2;A,q2,a,q1;A,q2,b,q0;B,s0,a,s0;B,s0,b,s1;B,s1,a,s1;B,s1,b,s0
```

Mapper class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.ByteWritable;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;






public class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, ByteWritable ,Text>{
    private  ByteWritable key1 = new ByteWritable();
    //private int n ;
    private int count =0 ;
    private Text wordObject = new Text();
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String ftext = value.toString();
        for (String line: ftext.split(";")) {
            
            wordObject = new Text();
            if (line.split(",")[2].equals("b")) {
                
                key1.set((byte) 'b');
                wordObject.set(line) ;
                context.write(key1,wordObject);
                continue ;
            }
                key1.set((byte) 'a');
                wordObject.set(line) ;
                context.write(key1,wordObject);
             
            
        
            
            
        }
        
        
        




        
    }
}
```

Reducer class:

```
import java.io.IOException;


import org.apache.hadoop.io.ByteWritable;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context;



public class MyReducer extends Reducer<ByteWritable, Text, ByteWritable ,Text>{
    
    private Integer count=0 ;

    




    @Override
    public void reduce(ByteWritable key, Iterable<Text>  values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        
        
        
        
        for(Text val : values ) {
            count++ ;
            
            
        }
        Text symb = new Text(count.toString()) ;
        context.write(key , symb);

    
    
}
}
```

Driver class:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.ByteWritable;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;




public class MyDriver extends Configured implements Tool {
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.printf("Usage: %s [generic options] <inputdir> <outputdir>\n", getClass().getSimpleName());
            return -1;
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Job job = new Job(getConf());
        job.setJarByClass(MyDriver.class);
        job.setJobName("separation ");
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ByteWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(ByteWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        return success ? 0 : 1;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new MyDriver(), args);
            System.exit(exitCode);
        }
}
```

Comment: the data i m using i is: "A,q0,a,q1;A,q0,b,q0;A,q1,a,q1;A,q1,b,q2;A,q2,a,q1;A,q2,b,q0;B,s0,a,s0;B,s0,b,s1;B,s1,a,s1;B,s1,b,s0"

Comment: I think you should use an else if statement, rather than using continue in your "line" loop

Comment: in the beginning i use" if else " and get same result 5 and 10 , i think java code is correct.  The problem is something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by putting the variable "count" inside the function "Reduce()".

Answer (score 0):

Does your input read more than one line that has 5 more `b`'s? I cannot reproduce for that one line, but your code can be cleaned up.

For the following code, I get output as

```
a 5
b 5
```

```
  static class Mapper extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<LongWritable, Text, ByteWritable, Text> {

    final ByteWritable keyOut = new ByteWritable();
    final Text valueOut = new Text();

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<LongWritable, Text, ByteWritable, Text>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      String line = value.toString();
      if (line.isEmpty()) {
        return;
      }

      StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, ";");
      while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String[] parts = token.split(",");
        String keyStr = parts[2];
        if (keyStr.matches("[ab]")) {
          keyOut.set((byte) keyStr.charAt(0));
          valueOut.set(token);
          context.write(keyOut, valueOut);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  static class Reducer extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer<ByteWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {

    static final Text keyOut = new Text();
    static final LongWritable valueOut = new LongWritable();

    @Override
    protected void reduce(ByteWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer<ByteWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable>.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      keyOut.set(new String(new byte[]{key.get()}, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
      valueOut.set(StreamSupport.stream(values.spliterator(), true)
                       .mapToLong(v -> 1).sum());
      context.write(keyOut, valueOut);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much my dear friend
I solved the problem by putting the variable "count" inside the function "Reduce()".   It seems that the issue is whether the variable is global or local. The problem is solved thank you once again